# How to style paper-dropdown-menu (how to use mixins?)

Tags: polymer, mixins, web-component, paper-elements

I want to style paper-dropdown-menu, specifically for example the paper-input components of the element. I guess I need to learn/understand how mixins work.

I probably need to combine the mixins of paper-dropdown-menu with the mixins/custom properties of paper-input-container, am I right about this?

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dropdown-menu
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-input-container

I don't even know where to start. The doc suggets something in curly braces as a default in a mixin, so the first step is probably something like:

```
paper-dropdown-menu {
    --paper-dropdown-menu: {
        something here?
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I barely understand this stuff myself, but I think after much struggle I might be able to shed enough insight to get you started.

You can define variables at the ":root" level that you want to use over and over again.  (Yes you actually type ":root".)  Consider:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    :root{
        --main-color: rgb(244,67,54);
        --dark-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
        --light-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);   
        --app-header-background-front-layer-background-image: url(../../img/ConcertChoirSATour.jpg);
        --app-header-background-front-layer-height: 400px;         
    }
</style>
```

Maybe you're using the Polymer appheader element, and you see in the docs that you can set the backgrounds with:

```
app-header {     
      --app-header-background-front-layer: {
          /*something or other*/              
      };
      --app-header-background-rear-layer: {
        /*something or other*/
      };
    }
```

Here's where you use the variables you assigned in your :root level using the var() keyword:

```
app-header {     
      --app-header-background-front-layer: {
          background-image: var(--app-header-background-front-layer-background-image);              
      };
      --app-header-background-rear-layer: {
        /* The header is blue when condensed */
        background-color: var(--main-color);
      };
    }
```

Here's some sample code:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    :root{
        --main-color: rgb(244,67,54);
        --dark-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.258824);
        --light-color: rgb(153, 153, 153);   
        --app-header-background-front-layer-background-image: url(../../img/ConcertChoirSATour.jpg);
        --app-header-background-front-layer-height: 400px;         
    }

    app-header {     
      --app-header-background-front-layer: {
          background-image: var(--app-header-background-front-layer-background-image);

      };
      --app-header-background-rear-layer: {
        /* The header is blue when condensed */
        background-color: var(--main-color);
      };
    }

    paper-icon-button {
      --paper-icon-button-ink-color: white;
    }

    paper-dropdown-menu {
        --paper-input-container-focus:{
            color: var(--main-color);
        }; 
        --paper-input-container: {
            color: var(--dark-color);
        };
        --paper-input-container-input: {
            color: var(--light-color);
        };
        --paper-input-container-label: {
            color: var(--main-color);
        };
    }
</style>
```

Comment: this is so underrated. awesome post.

Answer (score -3):

You can find some examples here:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling.html